# Trigger change event on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form that shows/ hide fields based on the user selection. Below is the code that is used for a `select` field and it works fine.

```
$('#pager').off('change', '.form_field select').on('change', '.form_field select', function(e) {

    load_all_options($(this), 'select', e);
});
```

I have the same function with different selectors like text and check box. Everything works fine during the change. But the problem is by default i have some fields populated, so on page load i need to trigger the change event so the relevant details are loaded properly..

can someone let me know the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You tried with $(document).ready(function () { load_all_options(); });?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe yes.. but nothing happens..when i pass `$(this)` and the selector, it returns empty

Comment: You need to show us the code of load_all_options()

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `document.ready`.create the array with selector names .Then join with `,` .its only trigger change event on particular selected element listed in array

```
const select_arr = ['.form_field select','.form_field input']// and use multiple select
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(select_arr.join(',')).trigger('change')
})
```